# Binning polar coordinates

Tags: python, pandas

My question is quite straight forward. I want to bin polar coordinates, which means that the domain in which I want to bin is limited by 0 and 360, where 0 = 360. Here start my problems, due to this circular behavior of the data, and as I want to bin each 1 degree starting from 0.5 degrees up to 355.5 degrees (Unfortunately due to the nature of the project binning from (0,1] until (359,360]), then, I have to make sure that there is a bin that goes from (355.5,0.5], which is obviously not what will happen by default.

I made up this script to better illustrate what I am looking for:

```
bins_direction = np.linspace(0.5,360.5,360, endpoint = False)
points = np.random.rand(10000)*360
df = pd.DataFrame({'Points': points})
df['Bins'] = pd.cut(x= df['Points'],
                             bins=bins_direction)
```

You will see that if the data is between 355.5 and 0.5 degrees, the binning will be NaN. I want to find a solution in which that would be (355.5,0.5]

So, my result (depending on which seed you set, of course), will look something like this:

```
          Points            Bins
0      17.102993    (16.5, 17.5]
1      97.665600    (97.5, 98.5]
2      46.697548    (46.5, 47.5]
3       9.832000     (9.5, 10.5]
4      21.260980    (20.5, 21.5]
5      47.433179    (46.5, 47.5]
6     359.813283             nan
7     355.654251  (355.5, 356.5]
8     0.23740105             nan
```

And I would like it to be:

```
          Points            Bins
0      17.102993    (16.5, 17.5]
1      97.665600    (97.5, 98.5]
2      46.697548    (46.5, 47.5]
3       9.832000     (9.5, 10.5]
4      21.260980    (20.5, 21.5]
5      47.433179    (46.5, 47.5]
6     359.813283    (359.5, 0.5]           
7     355.654251  (355.5, 356.5]
8     0.23740105    (359.5, 0.5]
```

Comment: Show sample input and output

Comment: `df['Bins'] = pd.cut(df['Points'].add(0.5)%360, bins=np.arange(360))`?

Answer (score 1):

Since you cannot have a `pandas` interval of the form `(355.5, 0.5]`, you can only have them as string:

```
bins = [0] + list(np.linspace(0.5,355.5,356)) + [360]

df = pd.DataFrame({'Points': [0,1,350,356, 357, 359]})

(pd.cut(df['Points'], bins=bins, include_lowest=True)
   .astype(str)
   .replace({'(-0.001, 0.5]':'(355.5,0.5]', '(355.5, 360.0]':'(355.5,0.5]'})
)
```

Output:

```
0       (355.5,0.5]
1        (0.5, 1.5]
2    (349.5, 350.5]
3       (355.5,0.5]
4       (355.5,0.5]
5       (355.5,0.5]
Name: Points, dtype: object
```